# get correct data from array

Tags: php, laravel-5

i am trying to decode array.
this is my array

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "tgPAddbrf3hI5tBIQIGyFYe9Y5RpwCj3rpZG5uVf"
  "resident_id" => array:4 [▼
    117 => "117"
    114 => "114"
    116 => "116"
    118 => "118"
  ]
  "available" => array:1 [▼
    116 => "2020-09-22"
  ]
  "out_of_community" => array:1 [▼
    118 => "2020-09-22"
  ]
]
```

i am using foeach to get answer like

```
resident_id  available    out_of_community
116         "2020-09-22"  null
118           null        "2020-09-22"
```

is it possible from foreach.
my code for it

and when i save it will shown "Call to a member function save() on array"

```
 foreach ( $arr['resident_id'] as $resident_id ) {
             $newArr[] = [
                'resident_id' => $resident_id,
                'present_in_community' => isset($arr['present_in_community'][$resident_id]) ? $arr['present_in_community'][$resident_id] : null,
                'out_of_community' => isset($arr['out_of_community'][$resident_id]) ? $arr['out_of_community'][$resident_id] : null,
             ]; 
            
             
             
        }
        
        $resident = new ResidentStatus;

            $resident->resident_id= $newArr['resident_id'];
            $resident->present_in_community = $newArr['present_in_community'];
            $resident->out_of_community = $newArr['out_of_community'];
            $resident->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
$arr = .... // this is the array you mentioned above

$newArr = [];

foreach ( $arr['resident_id'] as $resident_id ) {
     $newArr[] = [
        'resident_id' => $resident_id,
        'available' => isset($arr['available'][$resident_id]) ? $arr['available'][$resident_id] : null,
        'out_of_community' => isset($arr['out_of_community'][$resident_id]) ? $arr['out_of_community'][$resident_id] : null,
     ]; 
}

// finally save all entries in the db
ResidentStatus::insert( $newArr );
```

Note: make sure `available` and `out_of_community` columns are nullable by default in the db

Comment: ty and when i save to db it will show me "Call to a member function save() on array".

Comment: @VickyNehare you never mentioned anything related to saving anything in your question. you need to update your question and show how are you saving it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

   foreach ($value['resident_id'] as $resident_id ) {
     if(isset($data['available'][$resident_id ]) || isset($data['out_of_community'][$resident_id ]) ){
         echo '<td>'.($data['available'][$resident_id ]) ?? 'no entry' .'</td>';
          echo '<td>'.($data['out_of_community'][$resident_id ]) ?? 'no entry'.'</td>';
      }
   }
} ?>
```